# Can I connect to a sql node on a different machine (windows) from Mac?

Tags: mac, ssh, dns, remote-access, remote

GOAL: I'm trying to connect to a windows machine which has sql on it via "Connect to Server" on my Mac OS Mojave.

My questions:

1. Can I connect to a server on windows machine using Connect to Server on mac? I have a hostname myhostname.foo.bar.edu and I do have to login to a particular DOMAIN. I've tried

```
cifs://hostname myhostname.foo.bar.edu
login  DOMAIN\myloginusername 
password pass

on VPN, but not connecting.
```

2. Is it possible for me to ssh into a windows server from my mac? My ssh is setup, and I've tried to ssh 'DOMAIN\myloginname'@myhostname.foo.bar.edu, but connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I used an app called Microsoft Remote Desktop app and remote desktop into the windows machine. downloaded from https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/ . I guess there is no way for me to ssh into windows machine since windows uses linux and Mac uses Unix.